# Adding gtk graphics to existing console application - shared memory?

Tags: c, unix, gtk, cairo, sysv-ipc

I have concurent application (concurrent simulation of an airport) made with system v library (semaphores, message queue) and multiple processes.

I'm not allowed to use threads, that's why I have an processes thread and multiple 'planes' processes.

I would like to add some graphics to show traffic on an airport with GTK (with Cairo) library.

How to add graphic? When I tried to add it to airport process, gtk_main would block whole application. I thought about creating another process and add graphics to shared memory but I've read that it's not going to work.

What is the easiest/the best option?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should make a separate GUI process that the other processes can send messages to. One way to do this would be for your GUI process to export a [DBus interface](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) that the other processes can connect to. This way, when your GUI process receives a message from another process, your GTK main loop will emit a signal, and you can schedule a signal handler to deal with it and update the GUI accordingly.